# Can I send Email from javascript using sendgrid v3 api service

Tags: javascript, sendmail, sendgrid

Can I use sendgrid v3 api service to send email from javascript, assuming we are using it internally and there are no security concerns.

Comment: The Javascript language does not intrinsically prevent you from sending emails. So the answer to your question is yes. How to do it is a much broader answer.

Comment: Stack overflow is not suited for yes or no questions. Try it, then ask a question when you have trouble. But the answer is yes, you can.

Comment: thanks for helping.

Comment: When I am sending mail using browser, it first send OPTIONS request and then respond with error code:- 405 Method Not Allowed, what should I do